# iOS UITextFiled Crash When Landscape

Tags: ios

Firstly,I limit the input characters,only include number and alpha.
When controller rotate to landscape，I input a special symbol,such as '*'.
After that,I click the button in the red frame，App Crash!

[image]

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x181c5a1c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:165)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18069455c objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x181c61278 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:328)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x181c5e278 ___forwarding___ + 916 (NSForwarding.m:3120)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x181b5859c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   UIKit                           0x187bd0248 -[UIKeyboardImpl shouldShowCandidateBar] + 164 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:4261)
6   UIKit                           0x187ae0194 -[UIKeyboardImpl updateTextCandidateView] + 508 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:8597)
7   UIKit                           0x187adf498 -[UIKeyboardImpl clearInput] + 156 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:7663)
8   UIKit                           0x187af6028 -[UIKeyboardImpl updateForChangedSelectionWithExecutionContext:] + 280 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:4782)
9   UIKit                           0x187adf26c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 384 (UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:290)
10  UIKit                           0x188531c74 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addAndReturnTask:] + 132 (UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:410)
11  UIKit                           0x188531ee4 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performSingleTask:] + 248 (UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:484)
12  UIKit                           0x187c67120 -[UIKeyboardImpl updateForChangedSelection] + 92 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:4753)
13  UIKit                           0x187af495c -[UIKeyboardImpl selectionDidChange:] + 112 (UIKeyboardImpl.m:4867)
14  UIKit                           0x187af4404 __52-[UITextInputController _coordinateSelectionChange:]_block_invoke + 152 (UITextInputController.m:653)
15  UIFoundation                    0x187a2fd74 -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 56 (NSTextStorage.m:383)
16  UIKit                           0x187af4338 -[UITextInputController _coordinateSelectionChange:] + 156 (UITextInputController.m:639)
17  UIKit                           0x187cea998 -[UITextInputController selectAll] + 80 (UITextInputController.m:2774)
18  UIKit                           0x187cea89c -[UITextInputController clearText] + 48 (UITextInputController.m:2331)
19  UIKit                           0x187cea740 -[UITextField _clearButtonClicked:] + 376 (UITextField.m:5734)
20  UIKit                           0x187aea484 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 (UIApplication.m:4582)
21  UIKit                           0x187aea404 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80 (UIControl.m:609)
22  UIKit                           0x187ad48b8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452 (UIControl.m:694)
23  UIKit                           0x187ae9cf0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584 (UIControl.m:446)
24  UIKit                           0x187ae9818 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2484 (UIWindow.m:2120)
25  UIKit                           0x187ae4a60 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2988 (UIWindow.m:2290)
26  UIKit                           0x187ab552c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340 (UIApplication.m:10719)
27  UIKit                           0x1882a2a54 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1426)
28  UIKit                           0x18829c4bc __handleEventQueue + 784 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1622)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x181c08278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1943)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x181c07bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524 (CFRunLoop.c:1989)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x181c057c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804 (CFRunLoop.c:2821)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x181b34048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
33  GraphicsServices                0x1835ba198 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
34  UIKit                           0x187b202fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684 (UIApplication.m:2649)
35  UIKit                           0x187b1b034 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4091)
36  LCIphoneAdhocIP                 0x1002e5acc main + 88 (main.m:17)
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x180b185b8 start + 4
```

Comment: can you enable zombie so it will point you to where it actually crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> CoreFoundation                  0x181c61278 -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:328)

Your giving some "*" to the textField that is returned when you press Return Key, is neither a Number nor Alpha.

So it can't recognize @selector. So change your keyboard type like user wont be able to input such wrong symbols.

I prefer

```
[textField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet];
```

Comment: I used the UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet type.

Comment: Just use the delegate to limit the input

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string